# Any benefits to SQL Management Studio 2008 when only connecting to SQL Server 2005 databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

We run SQL Server 2005 exclusively for databases that we use (I'm trying to push to get them upgraded, but alas!). On the client side with Management Studio, are there any benefits to upgrading to SSMS2008 when only connecting to SQL Server 2005 databases? I've seen that [Intellisense won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250127/sql-server-management-studio-2008-intellisense), so I'm curious if it's worth the hassle.

Comment: I would have upgraded if Intellisense would've worked, I don't see any other benefits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's quite a few improvements <strike>intellisense is definitely a big one for developers</strike> (Intellisense only works against SQL Server 2008 databases, unfortunately), but there are also other things like T-SQL Debugger, Activity Monitor, the Object Explorer Details

[image]

[image]

Also, multi-server queries, and the ability to color the connections (get a visual clue whether you're on dev, test or prod system) and a lot more.

See some good background info [here at Simple-Talk](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/management-studio-improvements-in-sql-server-2008/).

Comment: I was fairly sure that intellisense for SSMS 2008 connected to a 2005 database would not work. Has MS relased a patch for this?

Comment: @MrEdmundo: no, you could be right. I'm using a third-party tool SQL Prompt anyway, so I never noticed - but good point!

Answer (score 1):

It is up to you. My favorite is search feature. See [link](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/management-studio-improvements-in-sql-server-2008/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Having worked with SQL 2005 since it came out, upgraded my client tools to 2008 when it came out, and still not upgraded our server, I don't think it is worth upgrading, especially if you aren't moving to SQL 2008 on your server anytime soon.  There is no real harm in upgrading, but you need to get familiar with a slightly different tool that IMO is neither worse nor better.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things to like about SQL2008 SSMS, even if you are connecting to SQL 2005 servers:

- Customize the columns in the object views, including some very useful ones like DB size
- When viewing a query execution plan, it will list any indexes that it recommends
- Color-code server connections
- Execute SQL statements against multiple servers

In our environment, we have a mix of SQL 2000, 2005, and 2008 servers, so I still use SQL 2005 SSMS to connect to all three (The new "Activity Monitor" in SQL2008 SSMS doesn't work for SQL 2000 servers.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to sound like taking sides, but [Toad 4.6](http://www.toadsoft.com/toadsqlserver/toad_sqlserver_beta.htm) rulez! :-)