# SQL 2008 Express & Intellisense?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, intellisense

Does the SQL 2008  Express have intellisense?

Comment: I think you mean the SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Intellisense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250127/sql-server-management-studio-2008-intellisense)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express, then yes. It's context-based depending on the database you're currently in, and not always 100%, but it is there.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post it was initially in there but later dropped:

[SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250127/sql-server-management-studio-2008-intellisense)

Answer (score 0):

SSMS 2008 has intellisense, but it works with SQL Server 2008 only.

If you need SQL autocomplete/formatting functionality for previous versions of SQL Server, take a look at [dbForge SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/) - a free add-in for SQL Server Management Studio that replaces built-in intellisense.

[image: dbForge SQL Complete - main view]

Answer (score 0):

In adding to our previous answer: recently we have released a new version of [dbForge SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/) that offers a bunch of [new features](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/features.html). All new features are available in shareware Standard Edition **(30-days free trial, $49.95)**.

You still can get all basic functionality, similar to v. 1.0, with Express Edition.